# How to identify the complete grid in the image using Python OpenCV

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, grid

I am currently working on an image processing task where I need to identify the grid cells and the create patches with each patch as the grid of the cell. I could generate the following output using the code below the image.

[image]

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import time 
from datetime import datetime
# from PIL import Image 
import torch 
import os, sys
import math
import cv2


# In[11]:


image = cv2.imread('../data/classes2.jpg')
print('rgb img shape : ',image.shape)
mask = np.zeros(image.shape, dtype=np.uint8)
gray = cv2.cvtColor(image,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
print('gray img shape : ',gray.shape)
thresh = cv2.threshold(gray, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV + cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[1]




# In[15]:


# Detect only grid
cnts = cv2.findContours(thresh, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
# print(cnts)
cnts = cnts[0] if len(cnts) == 2 else cnts[1]
for c in cnts:
    area = cv2.contourArea(c)
    print(area)
    if area > 10000:
        cv2.drawContours(mask, [c], -1, (255,255,255), -1)


# In[16]:


mask = cv2.cvtColor(mask, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
mask = cv2.bitwise_and(mask, thresh)


# In[17]:


# Find horizontal lines
horizontal_kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT, (55,1))
detect_horizontal = cv2.morphologyEx(mask, cv2.MORPH_OPEN, horizontal_kernel, iterations=2)
cnts = cv2.findContours(detect_horizontal, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
cnts = cnts[0] if len(cnts) == 2 else cnts[1]
for c in cnts:
    cv2.drawContours(image, [c], -1, (0,0,255), 2)


# In[18]:


# Find vertical lines
vertical_kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT, (1,25))
detect_vertical = cv2.morphologyEx(mask, cv2.MORPH_OPEN, vertical_kernel, iterations=2)
cnts = cv2.findContours(detect_vertical, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
cnts = cnts[0] if len(cnts) == 2 else cnts[1]
for c in cnts:
    cv2.drawContours(image, [c], -1, (0,0,255), 2)


# In[19]:


cv2.imshow('thresh', thresh)
cv2.imshow('mask', mask)
cv2.imshow('image', image)
cv2.waitKey()
```

However, I couldn't identify the grid lines completely in the contouring. I even tried to sharpen the image, but still no success. I am new to image processing. The original image is:

[image]

### Edit

one patch = one grid cell 
ie. one yellow colored cell or orange colored or white colored cell of a grid. My purpose is to identify the grid by contouring it and then crop the grid cell by cell where each square cell will act as the patch and then I need to identify the color of the patch/cell. Here each patch will be saved as an image.

I have modified the code but I am still getting some cells missing. Is there any better way to identify the cells and crop them as a patch and identify their color instead of first identifying the grid. Currently, I am getting the following output :

[image]

for the above output I have referred the code from : [link to grid identification in image python code](https://maker.pro/raspberry-pi/tutorial/grid-detection-with-opencv-on-raspberry-pi)

Trying it with the hard coding, I am getting the overlapped patches. The following code is what I tried:

```
image = cv2.imread(image_path + 'classes2.jpg')
#claculate patch pixels
white_x_pixels = 5
white_y_pixels = 5
grid_rows, grid_cols = 50,51
patch_row_pixels = round((image.shape[0])/50,2)
patch_col_pixels = round((image.shape[1])/51,2)
print('patch_row_pixels : ',patch_row_pixels)
print('patch_col_pixels : ',patch_col_pixels)
w = ceil(patch_col_pixels) 
h = floor(patch_row_pixels) 
print('w:{},h:{}'.format(w,h))
image_number = 0
coord_dict = {}
for r in range(grid_rows):#(49,50):#(grid_rows): 
#     y = white_y_pixels + r*(h)
    if r in [0,1,2]:
        y = white_y_pixels + r*(h) 
    else : 
        y = r*(h) - 1
    yh = int(y+h) - white_y_pixels
    y = int(y)
    for c in range(grid_cols):#(49,51):#(grid_cols):#(1):#(grid_cols):
        coord_dict[image_number] = {}
        if c in [0,1,2]:
            x = white_x_pixels + c*(w)# - white_x_pixels)#patch_col_pixels
        else: 
            x = c*(w) - (white_x_pixels - 1)
        xw = int(x+w) - white_x_pixels
        x = int(x)
        ROI = image[y:yh,x:xw]
        coord_dict[image_number]['x'] = x
        coord_dict[image_number]['x+w'] = x+w
        coord_dict[image_number]['y'] = y
        coord_dict[image_number]['y+h'] = y+h
        coord_dict[image_number]['w'] = w
        coord_dict[image_number]['h'] = h
        print(x,xw,y,yh)
        cv2.imwrite('ROI_'+str(image_number) + '.png',ROI)
#         cv2.imshow('ROI_'+str(image_number),ROI)
#         cv2.waitKey(0)
#         cv2.destroyAllWindows()
        image_number += 1
```

Comment: Your question is not at all clear. Could you please elaborate what is meant by patches and how you want your final output to be.

Comment: @VardanAgarwal : Can you now see the question, I have edited it ! pls let me know if you still do not find it clear.

Comment: thanks the question is clear now. Could you please clarify that are the grid cells or patches always going to be the same size like in the images you have shown because then the problem can easily be hard-coded. Or even if you can get size of one patch using image processing then all you need to do run nested loops and extract that size one at a time. Even if you didn't understand what I meant please clarify whether the patches will be same size or not then I will write a code for it.

Comment: @VardanAgarwal : all the patches will be of the same size

Comment: @VardanAgarwal : I am getting the overlapping patches with the logic you explained. Can you help me with the logic you told me for the fixed size patches? I have updated the post with the code?

Comment: Note that we prefer a technical style of writing here. We gently discourage greetings, hope-you-can-helps, thanks, advance thanks, notes of appreciation, regards, kind regards, signatures, please-can-you-helps, chatty material and abbreviated txtspk, pleading, how long you've been stuck, voting advice, meta commentary, etc. Just explain your problem, and show what you've tried, what you expected, and what actually happened.

Answer (score -1):

Sorry, I did not follow up after that. I tried hardcoding for your image provided but it is slightly skewed to the right and is not cropped properly (and I was too lazy to count them). But to show how it can be done I have cropped a smaller portion of the image.

[image]

You can try this code with your original image. However, you will need to crop it properly and correct that skew.

```
import cv2

img = cv2.imread('patches.jpg')
no_w = 7 # replace with no. of patches in width
no_h = 5 # replace with no. of patches in height
h, w = img.shape[:2]
pixels_w = round(w/no_w)
pixels_h = round(h/no_h)

for i in range(0, h, pixels_h):
    cv2.line(img, (0, i), (w, i), (0, 255, 0), 1)
for i in range(0, w, pixels_w):
    cv2.line(img, (i, 0), (i, h), (0, 255, 0), 1)

cv2.imshow('image', img)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

The result

[image]